# Spring beans - why would my private fields be static?

Tags: java, spring

I wonder if there's a good reason to mark Spring bean's private properties as `static`? Let's consider the following

```
@Component
public class SomeSpringBean {

    private Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    public String doSomeCalculations() {
        //some logic, getting values from map, doing some calculations
        return someVal;
    }
}
```

Of course Spring bean is a singleton, so why would I mark myMap as `static`? I've seen this in many projects but cannot find good reason for that.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason I can think for doing this is to make it clear to inexperienced developers that there is only one instance of the variable. However Spring Beans don't have to be singletons so this would break for some bean definitions.

I would therefore regard it as poor practice and avoid it.